# Ruby: How to insert three backslashes into a string?

Tags: ruby, escaping, backquote

I want to use backticks in ruby for a programm call.
The parameter is a String variable containing one or more backticks, i.e.
"&E?@@A`?". The following command yields a new label as its return value:

```
echo "&E?@@A\`?" | nauty-labelg 2>/dev/null
```

From a ruby program I can call it as follows and get the correct result:

```
new_label = `echo "&E?@@A\\\`?" | nauty-labelg 2>/dev/null`
```

I want to achieve the same using a variable for the label.
So I have to insert three slashes into my variable label = "&E?@@A`?" in order to escape the backtick. The following seems to work, though it is not very elegant:

```
escaped_label = label.gsub(/`/, '\\\`').gsub(/`/, '\\\`').gsub(/`/, '\\\`')
```

But the new variable cannot be used in the program call:

```
new_label = `echo "#{escaped_label}" | nauty-labelg 2>/dev/null`
```

In this case I do not get an answer from nauty-labelg.

Comment: `require 'shellwords'` and use `\`echo #{label.shellescape} | ...\``

Comment: Yay, that works! Thanks a lot, Stefan, you saved my day :)

Comment: `new_label, status = Open3.capture2('nauty-labelg', stdin_data: label)` would be another, maybe cleaner option.

Comment: Yes, that is a nice solution, but not for nauty, since it complains a missing newline and even if it succeeds there is some output stuff I got rid of by /dev/null. Anyhow, thanks also for this hint for future work, I hadn't been aware of these packages.

Comment: The title and first sentence contain typos. Please correct and proof your text in future.

Answer (score 0):

> So I have to insert three slashes into my variable label = "&E?@@A`?" in order to escape the backtick.

No, you only need to add one backslash for the output. To escape the `` ` `` special bash character. The other other two are only for representation proposes, otherwise it isn't valid Ruby code.

```sh
new_label = `echo "&E?@@A\\\`?" | nauty-labelg 2>/dev/null`
```

The first backslash will escape the second one (outputting one single backslash). The third backslash escapes the `` ` `` character (outputting one single `` ` ``).

You should only add backslashes before characters that have a special meaning within double quoted bash context. These [special characters](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) are: `$`, `` ` ``, `\` and `\n`. Those can be escaped with the following code:

```
def escape_bash_string(string)
  string.gsub(/([$`"\\\n])/, '\\\\\1')
end
```

For `` label = "&E?@@A`?" `` only the `` ` `` should be escaped.

```
escaped_string = escape_bash_string("&E?@@A\`?")
puts escaped_string
# &E?@@A\`?
```

Comment: Do you mean %x{...}? I tried it before asking but it cannot handle a backtick in the lable, even with your escape_bash_string since that will only insert two backslashes and I need three of them.

Comment: There should only be one backslash, since you expect the `&E?@@A\\`?` output. `\`echo "&E?@@A\\\\`?" | nauty-labelg 2>/dev/null\`` evaluates to a single backslash, since the first escapes the second, and the third escapes the `\`` (like I mentioned in the answer).